# How to detect if response is positive or negative on Facebook add friends dialog callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm adding [Facebook's add friend dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/) to a User show page in a rails app.

I've added the following code to the page

```
<%= link_to "Friend on Facebook", "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/friends/?id=#{@user.facebook_uid}&app_id=#{@my_app_id}&redirect_uri=#{user_url(@user)}" %>
```

So far so good, and I'm getting the following callback responses from Facebook:

```
If the user clicks to "Add Friend" (not sure where the additional # characters are coming from":
http://myapp.com/user/1?action=1#_=_

If the user clicks "Cancel":
http://myapp.com/user/1?action=0#_=_
```

I want to detect these responses, and in the User controller have the following code

```
def show
  ....
  if params[:action] == 1
    flash[:success] = "Friend added!"
  elsif params[:action] == 0
    flash[:error] = "Not added"
  else
   flash[:notice] = "no message"
  end
end
```

The Facebook callback is always dropping through the conditionals and generating the "no message" flash. I've tried various permutations, including converting to strings, integers, and adding the `#_=_` characters.

If I render `<%= params %>` in the view I see

```
{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"users", "id"=>"5"}
```

but the url in the addressbar has the Facebook param

```
http://myapp.com/user/1?action=1#_=_
```

While I'd like to find a fix for this, I'd also just like to understand what is happening. I would have assumed the action=1 would be added to the params response.

Comment: how about `params[:action].to_i == 1` ?

Comment: thanks @zakelfassi, I've tried transforming variables into strings and integers. But the problem appears to be that the response is not accessible. If I render `=params[:action].to_s` in the view I only see `show`.

Comment: (notice the curly bracket in `flash[:success} = "Friend added!"`) - does the Facebook redirect occur in both cases ? and if so, do you see a `/show/?action=*` or not ?

Comment: the curly bracket was an error in the question not in the code. Good catch though! The Facebook callback is generating the correct URL in the browser addressbar `http://myapp.com/user/1?action=0#_=_` though is appending these additional characters to the end. It seems strange that I am not able to render this action response on the page. Should I be able to?

Comment: if i render the full params I get `{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"users", "id"=>"1"}`. Yet the URL displays `http://myapp.com/user/1?action=0#_=_`. How do I access this response form the URL?

Comment: Apparently, those URL params aren't params, per se, but just a HTML history pushState, accessible only using javascript. What you could do for the serverside thing, add `&display=page` before `&redirect_uri=` so that it redirects literally to the page (though, it won't popup a addfriend dialog but redirect to a full add friend facebook page).